# Why is assigning to an unitialized variable slower

Tags: c++

In the following code, I allocate two arrays of ints dynamically, and only initialize one of them.
Why is it that assigning a value to the initialized variable is faster than assigning it to the uninitialized one? (~0.4 nanoseconds vs ~4 ns, compiled with g++ 7.4.0 with the -O3 flag, and n = 10000)

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#define NOW std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now
#define DURATION_CAST(x)                                                       \
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(x).count()

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    srand(time(nullptr));

    int* x = new int[n];
    int* y = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        x[i] = rand() / (RAND_MAX / 2);
    }

    auto t0 = NOW();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        x[i] = 1;

    auto t1 = NOW();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        y[i] = 1;

    auto t2 = NOW();
    double dt1 = DURATION_CAST(t1 - t0);
    double dt2 = DURATION_CAST(t2 - t1);

    std::cout << "Average time: " << dt1 / n << " ns" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Average time: " << dt2 / n << " ns" << std::endl;

    delete[] x;
    delete[] y;

    return 0;
}
```

[Here's a version with additional print statements](https://pastebin.com/MckNwHA3) in case the compiler optimizes away the important parts.

Comment: I see uninitialised arrays in your code. Where is the initialised one?

Comment: @Nina it's getting initialized by the `x[i] = rand() / (RAND_MAX / 2);`

Comment: Most likely because `x` is already in the cache.  Switch the loops around so you do `y` first and then compare the times.

Comment: @NathanOliver Gives the same results. The loop assigning to y is still slower.

Comment: @Kitegi You answered at own question :) Initialized is faster because of uninitialized needs initiation :P

Comment: @Raffallo I could be wrong, but I'm assuming the memory allocation happens when the arrays are created. Why does modifying allocated memory take longer the first time?

Comment: I don't really trust your test - because it's a sample of 1;  4ns isn't very long; even in computing.  Try doing the test ... a few million times (should still only take a couple of seconds).

Comment: I assumed you meant initialise at compile time vs initialise at runtime. Compile time will be faster because the data is written to the variable at compile time...

Comment: Oh, I know what's going on now.  There should be a dupe and I'll try and find it but in the mean time what happens is the OS doesn't actually give you the memory you requested in `int* y = new int[n];` until you actually go to use it.  So for `x` you use it already so the memory is allocated already.  for `y` you don't so you have the time of the memory getting allocated in the `y` loop.

Comment: @NathanOliver But the OS is required to give me contiguous memory, right? How can it do that without allocating it in one go?

Comment: @Kitegi It is reserved, but not actually allocated until you actually need it.

Comment: @Kitegi It'll still be contiguous, it just doesn't happen until you try to access it. That's an OS "optimisation" of a sort, or rather just how virtual memory works..